# Trouble getting field data from AJAX call

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-views

What I am trying to do, is when the financial institution is selected from the dropdown, I want to make an AJAX call to compare the selected FI against my query.

When I try to print out the selected data, I get `None` everytime.

Here is what I have so far.

edit.html javascript:

```
q = $("#investment_form").serialize();

function cdic_limit() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url investments-calc_cdic plan.id %}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: q,
        success: function(json) {
            alert('made it here');
            }
        });
    }
```

And in my ajax.py:

```
def calc_cdic(request, plan, *args, **kwargs):
    from investments.models import Investment
    from financial_institutions.models import FinancialInstitution
    from profiles.models import Profile
    from plans.models import Plan
    json = {}
    data = request.POST

    if request.is_ajax():
        print 'THIS IS THE PLAN: ', plan
        fiid = data.get('id_financial_institution')
        print 'THIS IS THE SELECTED FI:  ', fiid
        json['fiid'] = fiid

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(json), mimetype='application/json')
```

`id_financial_institution` is the field name on my form which I am trying to pull the data from.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In your Javascript code there is a variable `q`. What is the value of this variable? BTW, I'd replace $.ajax() with $.post().

Comment: Where is `q` coming from in the Ajax function?

Comment: What's `data:q`? Where is that variable coming from?

Comment: sorry q was an copy and paste error... that was used to add to a query string from an older function

Comment: If at all possible (i.e., unless it's sensitive), always post all the relevant code. Inevitably the parts you may think aren't important are the parts anyone else needs to see in order to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @ChrisPratt what else do you need to see?

Comment: Hang on, now you don't have `data` in your Ajax call at all. So how are you posting the field data?

Comment: @DanielRoseman edited, I have the data back in as well as where the q is coming from.

Comment: Look, this is why Chris said to post all the relevant code. When is that `serialize` call being made? Indeed, when is the `ajax` call being made?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the response you get is a 403 (Forbidden), you need to add a @csrf_exempt to your view ([1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)).